# How to test same .ipa build using Apple Testflight and iOS 7 device

Tags: ios, testflight, beta

I'm not sure if this problem is due to improper provisioning or whether it is an inherent problem with Apple's new Testflight Beta approach.

I have created a build, provisioned for Apple Testflight Beta which was approved and installed on iOS 8 devices. Since the new Testflight app is only available for iOS 8, I plan to manually install on a few iOS 7 devices. However, I am unable to install this .ipa on iOS 7 devices on Xcode (unless I am debugging). If I try to install the .ipa using Xcode 6 (using devices), I get the error,

"The executable was signed with invalid entitlements. The entitlements specified in your application’s Code Signing Entitlements file do not match those specified in your provisioning profile. (0xE8008016)."

Is it possible to provision the same .ipa to be installed on pre-iOS 7 devices and Apple Testflight? Ideally, we want to test the same binary on all devices.

Thanks

Comment: You could try resigning it with a development certificate to side-load it. I'm not sure you can side-load from devices unless it's signed development.

Comment: I don't think this is possible.